# Uri is not supported when saving pdf in server folder with nreco pdf generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();                     
htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = "~/files/";                           
htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(template);
```

Which throws the following error:

> Uri is not supported when saving pdf in server folder with nreco pdf generator.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a regular path to your file system like e.g. "C:\temp\myfolder\". Or use a . instead of ~ and backslashes:

```
htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = ".\\files\\";
```

If NReco is able to deliver you an byte-array or a stream you should prefer this instead of a file and return it directly.

UPDATE:

After takeing a look into the documentation of NReco all you need to do is following:

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();                     
htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = "<CORRECT_PATH_FOR_TOOL>";                           
var output = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(template); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("<OUTPUT_PATH>", output);
```

This should create your pdf in the OUTPUT_PATH.

Comment: I have tried htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = ".\\files\\";                                          
 but got error Access to the path '.\files\' is denied.

Comment: I have tried with overload of Generatepdf method htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(template,"","~/files/");   but now i got error  : Cannot generate PDF: Exit with code 1, due to unknown error. (exit code: 1) as i have no external reference in my html template.

Comment: Does the folder exists? Are you debugging your software on IIS or IIS Express? Check for user access rights - for testing set it to "Every one" with write privileges

Comment: yes i am able to upload logo or documents in the same folder.

Comment: Could you for testing set the path hard coded? E.g. "c:\temp\myFolder" instead of the relative one? Maybe you will need to make sure the correct folder is address by either using a config file or building the correct path dynamic

Comment: yes i have hard coded the path and it success but it generates the wkhtmltopdf.exe instead of  pdf file in folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OlaFW thanx for your effort.
I got my answer.

var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(template);  
     string filePath = "/files/Myfile.pdf";
     string Url = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filePath);                
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Url, pdfBytes);
```